# Correct frame for angular velocity in quaternion's kinematic

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, complex-numbers

I am reading a paper where the quaternion's kinematic is used, unfortunately the description of the angular velocity does not match with how it's computed, so I have a doubt on which frame $\omega$ is expressed. Given that $q$ express the orientation of a body A w.r.t frame O, and that $\omega$ is the angular velocity of body A w.r.t frame O, should $\omega$ be expressed in frame A or in frame O?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: Optimal Rendezvous Trajectories of a Controlled Spacecraft and a Tumbling Object (George Boyarko,∗ Oleg Yakimenko,† and Marcello Romano‡), pages 1-3

Answer (score 0):

I made calculation on my own and I found a result consistent with your question, assuming that indices ${1,2,3}$ indicate the vector part of the quaternion and index $4$ indicates the scalar part.

You get that result, if you use a Cartesian set of coordinates $\{x, y, z\}$ with the relative orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{\hat{x}}, \mathbf{\hat{y}}, \mathbf{\hat{z}}\}$ considered as steady (time derivative of the base vectors is identically null), to write the quaternion as
\begin{equation}
  q = q^{\alpha}_1 \mathbf{\hat{x}} + q^{\alpha}_2 \mathbf{\hat{y}} +  q^{\alpha}_3 \mathbf{\hat{z}} +  q^{\alpha}_4 \ ,
\end{equation},
so that
\begin{equation}
  q^\alpha_4 = \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}
  q^{\alpha}_1 \mathbf{\hat{x}} + q^{\alpha}_2 \mathbf{\hat{y}} +  q^{\alpha}_3 \mathbf{\hat{z}} =\sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}  \mathbf{\hat{n}} 
\end{equation}
and the angular velocity of the body w.r.t. the set of coordinates introduced before as
\begin{equation}
  \boldsymbol{\omega} = \omega_x^{\alpha} \mathbf{\hat{x}} +  \omega_y^{\alpha} \mathbf{\hat{y}} +  \omega_z^{\alpha} \mathbf{\hat{z}} \ .
\end{equation}

So, speaking the same language of your question, they're the components of the angular velocity of the body A w.r.t. the reference frame O, expressed in the reference frame O.

Answer (score 0):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

**The quaternion's kinematic**

\begin{align*}
&\b{\dot{z}}_i=\frac 12\b Q\,\b z_i\quad,\text{with}~\b z_i\cdot\b z_i=1
\end{align*}
where $~i~$ is inertial frame or body frame

if $~\b\omega~$ is given in inertial frame
\begin{align*}
 \b Q= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&-\omega_{{x}}&-\omega_{{y}}&-\omega_{{z
}}\\\omega_{{x}}&0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}
\\\omega_{{z}}&-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}

and if $~\b\omega~$ is given in body  frame

\begin{align*}
 \b Q=  \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&-\omega_{{x}}&-\omega_{{y}}&-\omega_{{z
}}\\\omega_{{x}}&0&\omega_{{z}}&-\omega_{{y}}
\\\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{z}}&0&\omega_{{x}}
\\\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}&-\omega_{{x}}&0
\end {array} \right]
\end{align*}